# How to sign a message without running testrpc?

Tags: web3js

I'd like to build a server that can sign a message in javascript.

This works fine:

```
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'); 
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
web3.eth.sign(message, accounts[0]);
```

However, I'm using infura on the server:

```
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/<key>, 0 )
```

This unfortunately does not support message signing.

Does anyone know how I can get the server to sign a message?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of web3.js are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

web3.js 1.0-beta has a method [`web3.eth.accounts.sign`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#sign) that should do what you want.

Per the [HDWalletProvider source code](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider/blob/master/index.js#L30), you should be able to call `web3.eth.getPrivateKey(<address>, ...)` to get the private key for an address you're using and then use `web3.eth.accounts.sign` with that private key to sign a message.